# List of wireless adapters that work with Linux : who maintains the list?

Tags: wireless

There is a list of wireless adapters that work with Linux/Ubuntu [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)

This list is not up-to-date - there are many entries for adapters that are no longer available, and almost certainly no entries for more recent adapters.

In my case I would like offer to details on the adapter I am using, a TP-Link TL-WN781ND. Who do I contact?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at [that page's editing history](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported?action=info), this shows the users who have edited the page.

It's a wiki. You can edit it yourself. I believe you have to register and log in. Then you can simply add the information on the adapter you're using. Please don't remove entries for adapters that are "no longer available" though--people still have them, and people still obtain them, used.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The thought of editing it myself simply didn't occur to me <blush>. I wouldn't in any case delete existing entries as I don't consider I have the authority (moral or otherwise) to do so.

Answer (score 3):

See that website. It has an option "login to edit". The URL you refer to has 'community' in it so can be maintained by the community. Though maybe with restrictions.

[image]

Also take note of the bottom:

[image]

> The material on this wiki is available under a free license, see [Copyright / License](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License) for details
>   You can contribute to this wiki, see [Wiki Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide) for details

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I don't think I ever scrolled right down to the bottom. Also see my comment to the previous responder. Thanks to all concerned.